# What memory used if a variable declared in anonymous namespace?

Tags: c++

What memory is used if a variable is declared in the anonymous namespace? Like:

```
namespace
{
   Class *pclass;

   void fSet()
   {
       pclass = new Class;

       pclass->func();

   }

   void fDes()
   {
      delete pclass;
      pclass = NULL;
   }

}
```

And is this safe?

Comment: It's safe.  It is the same memory that would be used if the variable was outside a namespace — the space as static variables in a source file would occupy.

Comment: The namespace doesn't make any difference to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The namespace has no effect on the memory used: the pointer to `Class` is in the global (static) memory area, while the object to which it points is in the dynamic (heap) memory area. This is as safe as using a named namespace.

Comment: It's safer than a named namespace in that it prevents name collisions. Not sure what notion of safety OP has in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I am not very sure but I think it's on code memory or somewhere in the data section of the program(also provided in binary file of the program). It is like global and static variables. Namespace is just for organizing code to avoid conflict in names.

I think it depends to the compiler where they will be placed in the code memory(and in the app binary file). But they will neither be in stack nor in heap.

The memory address the pClass can point to can be in stack, heap or code memory.

When it comes to security vulnerability, variables that reside in the code memory can be hacked easier than in stack and heap since they can be easily located in memory even before running the program.

When it comes to safety in organizing code I think there still be name collision if other source file uses the same "pClass" name since the compiler don't have clue which one will be used. But I'm also not sure about this. I don't know namespace behavior much. It is just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

It is safe. The C++ standard deprecates the usage of file statics and recommends the use of unnamed namespace instead.

Comment: Since C++11 static globals are not deprecated anymore.